# how to add object into array with hook state in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set the `id` property of a state object based on the `id` attribute of the button I clicked, and then append it into a state array and then store it in the localstorage. but there are weird things happening in my code:

1. when I clicked the 1st button, the `console.log` shows the `id` value of the 1st button (5) but the state object were still empty
2. then I clicked on the 2nd button, the `console.log` shows the `id` value of the 2nd button (12) but the state object now contains the value from the 1st button (5)
3. then I called the 3rd button, the `console.log` shows the `id` value of the 3rd button (100) but the state object contains the value of the 2nd button (12)
4. why are the `Button`s still look like a regular/default button even though I already added the `react-bootstrap` dependency, imported the `Button` component, and applied the `variant="link"` in the `Button`?

here's my code (and the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-cherry-vxv842?file=/src/App.js:0-1865))

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function App() {
  const [cartList, setCartList] = useState([]);
  const [cartItem, setCartItem] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    let localCart = localStorage.getItem("cartList") || "[]";
    console.log("localcart", localCart);
    if (localCart) {
      localCart = JSON.parse(localCart);
    }
    setCartList(localCart);
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (e, item) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const arr = e.target.id.split("-");
    const selectID = arr[1];
    console.log("selectID", selectID);
    setCartItem({ ...cartItem, id: selectID });
    console.log("cartItem", cartItem);

    let itemIndex = -1;
    console.log("cartlist", cartList);
    for (let i = 0; i < cartList.length; i++) {
      if (cartItem && selectID === cartList[i].id) {
        itemIndex = i;
      }
    }
    if (itemIndex < 0) {
      console.log("added to cartList on index", itemIndex, cartItem);
      setCartList([...cartList, cartItem]);
      localStorage.setItem("cartList", JSON.stringify(cartList));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Button
        variant="link"
        id="item-5"
        onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, cartItem)}
      >
        item no.5
      </Button>
      <Button
        variant="link"
        id="item-12"
        onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, cartItem)}
      >
        item no.12
      </Button>
      <Button
        variant="link"
        id="item-100"
        onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, cartItem)}
      >
        item no.100
      </Button>

      <div>
        {cartList.length > 0 ? (
          cartList.map((item, index) => <div key={index}>{item.id}</div>)
        ) : (
          <div>there is no data here</div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems number ***1***, ***2***, ***3*** are all caused by the same reason: `setCartItem` works asynchronously so when you do this:

```
setCartItem({ ...cartItem, id: selectID });
console.log("cartItem", cartItem);
```

The value that you print in the `console.log` is still the old state because it doesn't wait for the `setCartItem` to complete the update. So, if you want to do a `console.log` of the new state each time it changes you can use instead a `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
 console.log("cartItem", cartItem); // this will be executed each time the cartItem has been changed
}, [cartItem])
```

About the question number ***4***, make sure to import the bootstrap css file:

```
/* The following line can be included in your src/index.js or App.js file*/

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

More infos here in the official site:
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#stylesheets